# How can I output the just selected value from a multiple select (select2)?

Tags: jquery, select

I try to output ONLY the last selected option, but I have difficulties:

```js
$("#multipleSelectExample").select2();
$("#multipleSelectExample").on("select2-selecting", function(e) {
  var selected = $(this).val();
  console.log("You just selected Option " + selected);
});
```

```css
.selectRow {
    display : block;
    padding : 20px;
}
.select2-container {
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://select2.github.io/select2/select2-3.5.1/select2.js"></script>
<link href="http://select2.github.io/select2/select2-3.5.1/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<body>
    <div class="selectRow">
        <!-- Using data-placeholder below to set place holder value versus putting in configuration -->
        <select id="multipleSelectExample" data-placeholder="Select an option" multiple>
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
            <option value="4">Option 4</option>
            <option value="5">Option 5</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</body>
```

[jsfiddle.net/n4n5Y/568](http://jsfiddle.net/n4n5Y/568)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("#multipleSelectExample").select2();
var selectedLengthPrev = 1;
$("#multipleSelectExample").on("change", function(e) {
  var selectedLengthNow = $('.select2-choices li').length;
  if (selectedLengthNow > selectedLengthPrev) {
    var lastSelected = $('.select2-choices li')[selectedLengthNow - 2];
    var lastSelectedVal = $(lastSelected).find('div').html();
    console.log("You just selected Option: " + lastSelectedVal);
  }
  selectedLengthPrev = selectedLengthNow;
});
```

```css
.selectRow {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
}

.select2-container {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<body>
  <div class="selectRow">
    <select id="multipleSelectExample" data-placeholder="Select an option" multiple>
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
            <option value="4">Option 4</option>
            <option value="5">Option 5</option>
        </select>
  </div>
</body>
```

#### [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/sajibcse68/n4n5Y/571/)

Comment: I cannot use "change" function unfortunately, because I only want to fire on select and not on remove

Comment: Yes, working, but there is also an output when I remove an option

Comment: ah no, it is not working. With your code the output is always the last in the row. But not the latest selected.

Comment: Yes one moment.

Answer (score 0):

#### Please refer to official documentation for further events & details

[Select2 Events Documentation](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events)

```
$(`#multi-select-select2`).select2();
```

##### Getting change one by one

```
$(`#multi-select-select2`).on(
        "select2:select",
        function (e) {
          var data = e.params.data;
          console.log(data);
        }
      );
      $(`#multi-select-select2`).on(
        "select2:unselect",
        function (e) {
          var data = e.params.data;
          console.log(data);
        }
      );
```

##### Getting array on change

```
$(`#multi-select-select2`).on(
        "change.select2",
        function (e) {
          console.log($(`#multi-select-select2`).select2("data"));
        }
      );
```